# How to use react hook form -remove() in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

in react hook form with typescript , remove() is not working. Can anybody tell-How to use remove() in typescript?

================================================================

```
const { register, handleSubmit, errors, getValues, control } = useForm({
        teamSize: [
            {
                teamMember: 'Rajesh',
            },
        ],
    } as any)
    const { fields, append, remove } = useFieldArray({
        control,
        name: 'teamSize',
    })
----------------------------------------------------------
{fields && fields.map((item, index) => (
 <Grid item xs={3} 
sx={{ mr: 3, mb: 2 }}
><Chip sx={{ borderRadius: '5px' }}label={item.teamMember} 
 onClick={() => remove(index)} onDelete={() => { remove(index)              
}}                   
 />
  </Grid>
 ))}
```

Comment: Please elaborate e.g. where does `remove()` come from, maybe share the function definition and what you mean by "is not working".

Comment: its giving me an error like....Uncaught TypeError: data.slice is not a function or its return value is not iterable
    at removeAt (react-hook-form.es.js:1455:1)
    at removeArrayAt (react-hook-form.es.js:1468:1)
    at remove (react-hook-form.es.js:1625:1)
    at onClick (otherdetails.tsx:177:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback

Answer (score 0):

there is no remove function in java-script you can elaborate your question more by telling what you want by remove.
I am guessing you want to remove the element on clicking so you have to write a function for that.
i used a filter function to remove the element that is clicked.
if you want something else you can tell me

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
const [fields, setFields] = useState(["a", "b", "c", "d"]);
  const removeFields = (indexToRemove) => {
  const remainingFields = fields.filter((data, index) => {
      if (index !== indexToRemove) return data;
    });

    setFields(remainingFields);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {fields.map((data, index) => {
        return <h1 onClick={() => removeFields(index)}>{data}</h1>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: See react hook form usefield array